# 15-20W amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, power-amplifier

I'm trying to build a small radio amplifier which will deliver around 15V at 1A at 250kHz from a 0.2V input of the same frequency. I have searched for and tried as many online circuits as I can which will fit on the breadboard (just no absolutely massive ones). I tried a push/pull circuit as shown:

[image]

but the simulation applet on this site http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ shows that it would never get enough current to the output.

Could someone please point me to a circuit which can deliver what I specified above?

I have AC/DC adapters which can supply 12V at 2A and the breadboard is roughly 11cm x 16cm.

Comment: With 500 ohm load, how much current do you expect with 15 volts?

Comment: To deliver 20 W to a 500 ohm load, you'll need to drive it with 100 V. Your circuit will work (if you choose components that can survive 100 V) but you'll need 140 V supplies in place of the 17 V you have.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but the 500 is representative of an antenna-like arrangement; so I expect to be able to modify that resistance value as needed.

Comment: If you reduce the output resistor, Falstad will show you delivering more power. But you'd have to drop it to 10 or so ohms to be able to get 20 W with 17 V supplies.

Comment: "I expect to be able to modify that resistance value as needed." OK. So, when you modified your simulation so as to get the power you needed, what resistance was the result? Are you sure you can make an antenna which will perform like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM318 has a GBWP of 15 MHz. Since you need 15V/0.2V = 75 times gain you can ideally get 15MHz/75 = 200 kHz bandwidth. For a realistic design for a 250 kHz amplifier that should be at least 500 kHz.

All the voltage gain needs to come from the opamp as those CC stages only provide current gain. Using two TIP41/TIP42 in cascade like that is unusual, normally the first stage would use transistors which can handle less power but have a higher beta.

Circuits with large currents (more than say 0.1 A) will always have issues when made on a breadboard. There will be too much series and contact resistance for the circuit to work properly. Above 0.1 A I recommend **soldered** connections.

Oh and I consider falstad.com to be for **educational** purposes only, it is not suited to "design" anything more than really basic.

Comment: upvoted, especially for the GBWP consideration. The TIP42 has GBPW of only 3 MHz – so the LM318 isn't even the culprit, but I'd never have guessed that if I hadn't looked into the datasheet after reading your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info. But I am surprised by the GBWP being too low since I haven't had any problems with getting the required voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Your load is 500 Ω. The current you can push through that from a 15 V supply is pretty clearly limited by U/R = 0.03 A.

Then, you further reduce your current sourcing abilities by using TIP41 / 42 – these are positively ancient, and

- have a very low current amplification,
- low bandwidth, i.e. even lower gain at the frequencies you want to work, and
- have a high base-emitter voltage, which reduces your effective voltage swing even further.

I'd argue that the transistor output stage is counterproductive, and you'd just go ahead, and buy an Opamp that's simply beefier and can source more current into a lower-resistance load. 250 kHz isn't that high a frequency for modern power-opamps.

If your TX antenna really has 500Ω impedance, consider somehow transforming its impedance to a much lower value, so that with your (already pretty nice, but for this application) limited supply voltage you can actually work it. A simple transformer might do that, and you'd also separate the potential of your semiconductors from the antenna.

I strongly advise against using old magazine-copied schematics, if they came without any explanation of functionality, in case that's how you came across this circuit. You can't tweak a circuit if you can't understand it, and you can't understand it if someon just took a circuit from a different publication and omitted the thoughts of whoever designed that. Circuits that you find online *very* often are from the categorie of "1970s' magazine copied by 1980's magazine, scanned by guy in shed, omitting half of the accompanying info, then copied without attribution by some guy running a website with a collection of circuits",  and that's really not worth the trouble. Don't spend your time trying out a lot of different circuits, instead get ahold of a good book (the ARRL and others have handbooks, some even available online for free), and read that, and build the first circuits.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using PI networks to transform impedance levels, thus some filtering is also available in the PI resonances, why not consider some high-current MOSFET GATE_DRIVERS? Be sure to heatsink them (use the TO_220 cases),
and start out with a GNDPLANE; do not breadboard; use several 0.1 uF caps directly at the VDD pins (that is, 1mm away from the VDD pins, perhaps soldered UNDER the pin, installed by hand soldering.)

Again, these will output "square waves", with 10-30nanoSecond edges, clearly not sin waves. Try to switch at the zero crossings. Use an LC interface, having the Gate_Driver drive the inductor.

Comment: While this is a reasonable recommendation for someone building a high power amp from scratch, I think it's about 20 dB above OP's level of understanding..